# What's the name of an 'extended' cycle graph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm looking for the name of a regular cycle graph, where each node is connected with it's *k* neighbors. In particular, I'm looking for a lemma at Wolfram Mathworld or Wikipedia.

An examples of this graph is:

[image: Example 'extended' ring graph]

(source: http://www.patternsinnature.org/Book/RegularNetworks.html)

So far, the terms I've encountered are:

- "circular lattice" at http://www.patternsinnature.org/Book/RegularNetworks.html
- "regular ring lattic"e at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watts_and_Strogatz_model

So it seems that the common name is somehting like:
  (Extended or regular) (ring or cycle) (graph or lattice)

Unfortunately, I've not found any Lemma's yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for something related to Circulant Graphs. 
Below is a link:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirculantGraph.html

Graphs in this class are parameterized by certain "jump" amounts. They're essentially like generalized petersen graphs except the "spokes" are contracted.